# I want to ask why my query for null value column result in empty value?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to fetch array of my table. but why my null column value result "" or Empty value ?

MY DB
Field1, Field2, Field3
1, John, NULL
2, Karen, NULL
etc...

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM password";
$result = $conn->query($select);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
echo $row[2]."<br>";
}
```

i except the output to be null for each echo, like  
NULL
NULL
etc...

but the actual output is "" = empty,

can anyone explain this ?
thanks

Comment: The same reason the `echo null` prints an empty string.

Comment: It's how PHP is designed, when you echo a null/false value, it outputs as empty string.

Comment: you can try doing a var_dump instead of the echo

Comment: A `password` table sounds like the start of a bad DB design.

Comment: its not password table haha @user3783243 i just assume any table.. bcs any table with null value reslut empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, when you echo a null value, it prints an empty string.
If you want to see the "NULL" string, you should check the null value:

```
echo  (is_null($row[2]) ? "NULL" : $row[2])."<br>";
//or in PHP 7:
echo  $row[2] ?? "NULL" ."<br>";
```

Comment: $row[2] ?? "NULL"  this is work !!!

i try (is_null( ... )) not work, is this function deprecated ?

Comment: @DavidAdiel Nope, is_null is not deprecated. You can additionally write ($row[2] === null) instead of is_null.

Answer (score 0):

A variable or column that is assigned null, means that its empty, that is, no value.
NULL is supposed to indicate the absence of a value, rather than being thought of as a value itself. It's the empty slot, it's the missing information, it's the unanswered question. It's not a jumped-up zero or empty set.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

```
$name = null

if($name == 0) returns true
```

Using strict comparison

```
if ($name === 0) returns false

if(empty($name)) returns true
```